# C++ Accessing a data value from an pointer in an array, via pointer to another element and element size

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, data-structures

Hope that title made sense!

whilst creating a menu system, I'am trying to access data from a pointer in the nTh element of an array of structs, where I have the address of the pointer in the 1st(0) elements data value, the index of the element I wish to access and the size of the array elements.

the example code returns the correct result for the "display_value(0);", but not for any other elements.
I can see something must be wrong with my logic/math in the "elementToDisplay = sensorData[0].valueToDisplay + (sensorData[0].arrayElementSize * thermistorIndex);" line.. not creating the correct memory address but I can't work it out!

Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct thermistors_t{
  int itemIDNo;
  int  valueToDisplay;
  int noOfSamples;};

thermistors_t thermistors[]{
    {1, 10, 100},
    {2, 20, 200},
    {3, 30, 300}};

struct sensorData_t{
  int itemIDNo;
  int *valueToDisplay;
  int arrayElementSize;};
  
const sensorData_t sensorData[]{
    {1, &thermistors[0].valueToDisplay, sizeof(thermistors_t)}};


void display_value(int thermistorIndex){
  void *elementToDisplay;
  int *intToDisplay;

  elementToDisplay = sensorData[0].valueToDisplay + (sensorData[0].arrayElementSize * thermistorIndex);
  intToDisplay = (int*)elementToDisplay;
  cout << *sensorData[0].valueToDisplay << ", ";
  cout << *intToDisplay << '\n';
}


int main() 
{
  display_value(0);
  display_value(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages.

Comment: Use `thermistors[thermistorIndex].valueToDisplay`

Comment: Well the way to access things is weird (it is common in OpenGL though), but the bug is simple: you’re adding `arrayElementSize` to  `int *` and convert the result to `void *`, while you should cast to `char *` first (not even `void *`, it may work but not required to IIRC) and add to that.

Comment: @numzero
Yeah - I ended up trying this whilst creating a menu system, being able to access like this would save me from having individual code for different sensor types.

Comment: So did you try using `(char *)sensorData[0].valueToDisplay` in place of `sensorData[0].valueToDisplay`?

Comment: @numzero  thanks
I tried as you suggested (or how I interpreted it!) by changing
  int arrayElementSize to  char arrayElementSize in sensorData_t

but get the same result, I'm not sure I' actually doing as you suggest!

Comment: You misinterpreted it. The type of `arrayElementSize` doesn’t matter as long as it is integral (both `int` and `char` are). What does matter is the type of the other summand, the pointer. Adding 1 to an int pointer is not the same as adding 1 to a char pointer: the latter increments the pointer by one byte but the former increments by one *int*. So you need to cast your pointer to a char pointer, *then* add, and *then* cast back to int pointer.

Comment: @numzero Ahh ha... that done it - thanks
I can't see how to mark your answer as good

Comment: @numzero - thanks for the explanation - my mind gets a bit warped around pointers and stuf,f but you explanation helped greatly